# net-snmp linker error with camke (undefined reference to)

Tags: c, cmake, snmp, undefined-reference, net-snmp

I'm having problems linking the net-snmp library with CMake. I successfully built the library with MinGW according to the instructions in the readme.win32 file, and now I want to run the snmpdemoapp (example demo code). However, I am unable to correctly link the library.

I've written CMake below to link the library to my code, and it generates correctly, but when I try to build the following, errors appear.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.2)


project("PROJECT_NAME")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(C:/nsnmp/include)

find_library(NETSNMPAGENT "netsnmpagent")

find_library(NETSNMPMIBS "netsnmpmibs")

find_library(NETSNMP "netsnmp")



add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" Main.c)

target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" ${NETSNMPAGENT} ${NETSNMPMIBS} ${NETSNMP})
```

```
[main] Building folder: Psnmp 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build c:/Users/Hanaei/Desktop/Psnmp/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [1/1 100% :: 0.354] Linking C executable PROJECT_NAME.exe
[build] FAILED: PROJECT_NAME.exe 
[build] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -g  CMakeFiles/PROJECT_NAME.dir/Main.c.obj -o PROJECT_NAME.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libPROJECT_NAME.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmpagent.a  C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmpmibs.a  C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(mib.o): in function `dump_realloc_oid_to_inetaddress':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/mib.c:4085: undefined reference to `__imp_ntohl'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(mib.o): in function `parse_one_oid_index':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/mib.c:3877: undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(parse.o): in function `compute_match':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/parse.c:1294: undefined reference to `regcomp'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/parse.c:1297: undefined reference to `regfree'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/parse.c:1296: undefined reference to `regexec'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/parse.c:1297: undefined reference to `regfree'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(snmp_api.o): in function `_sess_open':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/snmp_api.c:1699: undefined reference to `__imp_setsockopt'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(snmp_api.o): in function `snmp_add_var':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/snmp_api.c:7514: undefined reference to `__imp_inet_addr'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(asn1.o): in function `asn_parse_float':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/asn1.c:2554: undefined reference to `__imp_ntohl'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(asn1.o): in function `asn_build_float':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/asn1.c:2628: undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(asn1.o): in function `asn_parse_double':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/asn1.c:2745: undefined reference to `__imp_ntohl'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(asn1.o): in function `asn_build_double':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/asn1.c:2823: undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(asn1.o): in function `asn_realloc_rbuild_float':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/asn1.c:3859: undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(asn1.o): in function `asn_realloc_rbuild_double':
[build] C:\Users\Hanaei\Downloads\net-snmp-5.9.3\snmplib/asn1.c:3937: undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/nsnmp/lib/libnetsnmp.a(system.o): in function `get_myaddr':
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we discourage using **images** for represent **logs**. Instead, paste the log into the question as **text**. After pasting, the log could be formatted as a code. See also [ask] and that [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  Thank you for your welcome. I've edited my questions. now could you please tell me what should I do?